# Create floppy image from kernel file for bochs

Tags: kernel

This is a newbie question and I have googled for a while but does not find a way to solve, so I just post it here.

I was reading James Molloy's kernel development tutorials. He wrote the kernel image into floppy.img using floppy driver with the following script

```
sudo /sbin/losetup /dev/loop0 floppy.img
sudo mount /dev/loop0 /mnt2
sudo cp src/kernel /mnt2/kernel
sudo umount /dev/loop0
sudo /sbin/losetup -d /dev/loop0
```

However, I had no floppy on my machine. I also tried to create the floppy.img using the following method

```
1.create empty 1.44MB image file by dd command (dd bs=512 count=2880 if=/dev/zero of=myfloppy.img)

2.format the image file by mkfs.msdos
3.mount the image file to some mount point
4.copy kernel to the mount point
5.umount the virtual floppy image file
```

But it does make bochs work. Does any one know any method to create the floppy.img which bochs can run on it?

BTW: I also tried create iso image using mkisofs command, but bochs also cannot run on the iso image. If any one know how to make bochs work using iso image, it will be nice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check the bochs configuration (there are a lot of variables to be set).

What does bochs say when started?

Does the floppy image boot at all if formatted and empty? (It should complain that there is no operating system or some such).

Answer (score 0):

when bochs is installed on your machine, you can just type "bximage" and follow the prompt to create several different kinds of image.

Here is an example:

type bximage

========================================================================
                                bximage
  Disk Image Creation / Conversion / Resize and Commit Tool for Bochs

## $Id: bximage.cc 12690 2015-03-20 18:01:52Z vruppert $

1. Create new floppy or hard disk image
2. Convert hard disk image to other format (mode)
3. Resize hard disk image
4. Commit 'undoable' redolog to base image
5. Disk image info
6. Quit

Please choose one [0] 1

Create image

Do you want to create a floppy disk image or a hard disk image?
Please type hd or fd. [hd] ?
Your choice (?) did not match any of the choices:
fd, hd

Do you want to create a floppy disk image or a hard disk image?
Please type hd or fd. [hd] fd

Choose the size of floppy disk image to create, in megabytes.
Please type 160k, 180k, 320k, 360k, 720k, 1.2M, 1.44M, 1.68M, 1.72M, or 2.88M.
 [1.44M] 
.......